# window.print can't work in node-webkit

Tags: node-webkit

I hava a web project with express. when I convert the project to node-webkit use package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello"
  "main": "http://localhost:3001",
  "node-main": "index.js",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "frame": true,
    "width": 1170,
    "height": 780
  },
  ...
}
```

it can work well.  but there is a button in one page, it will call `window.print()` on click and now it can't work in node-webkit application.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong? or are there any other solution to print the page？

Comment: Try to add the `pdf.dll` file

Comment: Did you eventually get this to work? I am interested in your findings?

Comment: @Kendall No, I haven't find a solution

Comment: Looking for a solution on this as well. :(